# Apache Airflow SparkSQLOperator keeps printing empty logs

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I wrote a very simple airflow dag as follows:

```
import airflow                                                                                                                                                
from airflow import DAG                                                                                                                                        from airflow.contrib.operators.spark_sql_operator import SparkSqlOperator                                                                                     
from datetime import timedelta                                                                                                                                 from datetime import datetime as dt                                                                                                                           

default_args = {                                                                                                                                              
             'owner': 'zxy',                                                                                                                                       'depends_on_past': False,                                                                                                                             
             'email_on_failure': True,                                                                                                                                      'email_on_retry': True,                                                                                                                               
             'retries': 1,                                                                                                                                         
             'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)                                                                                                                   
             }                                                                                                                                                     

dag = DAG(                                                                                                                                                    
             'my_first_dag',                                                                                                                                      
             default_args=default_args,                                                                                                                            
             #start_date=dt.strptime('2018-05-16', '%Y-%m-%d'),                                                                                                    
             start_date=airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),                                                                                                           
             description='My First Airflow DAG',                                                                                                               
             schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=5))                                                                                                               

sql = r'''select count(u) from some_table where time=20180513 and platform='iOS' '''                                                    
t1 = SparkSqlOperator(task_id='Count_Ads_U', conn_id='spark_default',sql=sql, dag=dag)
```

Then I ran `airflow scheduler` to schedule the job.

The job gave the right number successfully, but the job kept printing blank logs as follows hence cannot stop sucessfully:

> [2018-05-16 06:33:07,505] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,505] {spark_sql_hook.py:142} INFO - b'18/05/16
>   06:33:07 INFO spark.    SparkContext: Successfully stopped
>   SparkContext\n'
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,506] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,506] {spark_sql_hook.py:142} INFO - b'18/05/16
>   06:33:07 INFO util.     ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called\n'
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,506] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,506] {spark_sql_hook.py:142} INFO - b'18/05/16
>   06:33:07 INFO util.     ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory
>   /tmp/spark-fbb4089c-338b-4b0e-a394-975f45b307a8\n'
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,509] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,509] {spark_sql_hook.py:142} INFO - b'18/05/16
>   06:33:07 INFO util.     ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory
>   /apps/data/spark/temp/spark-f6b6695f-24e4-4db0-ae2b-29b6836ab9c3\n'
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,902] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,902] {spark_sql_hook.py:142} INFO - b''
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,902] {spark_sql_hook.py:142} INFO - b''
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,902] {spark_sql_hook.py:142} INFO - b''
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,902] {spark_sql_hook.py:142} INFO - b''
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {spark_sql_hook.py:142} INFO - b''
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {spark_sql_hook.py:142} INFO - b''
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {spark_sql_hook.py:142} INFO - b''
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {spark_sql_hook.py:142} INFO - b''
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {spark_sql_hook.py:142} INFO - b''
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {spark_sql_hook.py:142} INFO - b''
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {spark_sql_hook.py:142} INFO - b''
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {spark_sql_hook.py:142} INFO - b''
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {spark_sql_hook.py:142} INFO - b''
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,904] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {spark_sql_hook.py:142} INFO - b''
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,904] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {spark_sql_hook.py:142} INFO - b''
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,904] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:
>   [2018-05-16 06:33:07,903] {spark_sql_hook.py:142} INFO - b''

The empty log went on endlessly until I stopped the scheduler by Ctr+C.

airflow version is v1.9.0.

Comment: @tobi6 Indeed the subprocess seems to keep running, but I fixed it in a different way and you check it out in my own answer below, although I still don't know why the subprocess didn't stop after successful execution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

This is caused by a `byte literal vs string literal` problem if your are using Python 3.x(line 146 of https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/spark_sql_hook.py):

```
for line in iter(self._sp.stdout.readline, ''):
    self.log.info(line)
```

The sentinel used in the iter is '', which is the empty `string literal`. But the actual content in the stdout are `byte literals` instead of `string literals`(see this post for reference: [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)), as can tell from the `b` prefix in each line of log, so the for loop never ends for some reason.

I fixed the problem by replacing `''` with `b''`.